# Installing/using PyVISA-py on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pi-3, software-installation

I am trying to install PyVISA-py on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B without internet connection, because I understand that the normal PyVISA needs the NI backend that is not supported on the Pi. However, I cannot get it to install on my Pi.

I downloaded the package and am trying the command

```
sudo python3 setup.py
```

through the directory it is saved in, and also

```
sudo pip install pyvisa-py
```

but neither are working. I am getting the following error:

```
No distributions at all found for pyvisa-py
```

Possibly I am not downloading it to the right place? Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with your command. After you download the package, run the following command:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

That is how you install a package (you were missing the `install` at the end).

If you have no internet access, you will need to solve the dependencies by hand (i.e., install ALL the packages required), so you will need to do a bit of digging.

I also strongly suggest you to use virtual environments, which will allow you to work without `sudo` and without the risk of overwriting packages needed in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, are you running jessie release? Please check network connections.

You may wish to perform `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`.

You may also want to update PIP (best to do in virtualenv) `pip install --upgrade pip`

Just performed the following on jessie

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 visa-test
$ source visa-test/bin/activate
(visa-test)$ pip install pyvisa-py
  Downloading/unpacking pyvisa-py
  Downloading PyVISA-py-0.2.tar.gz (50kB): 50kB downloaded
    Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-rwx4b_rx/pyvisa-py/setup.py) egg_info for package pyvisa-py
  Downloading/unpacking pyvisa>=1.8 (from pyvisa-py)
  Downloading PyVISA-1.8.tar.gz (429kB): 429kB downloaded
    Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-rwx4b_rx/pyvisa/setup.py) egg_info for package pyvisa
  Installing collected packages: pyvisa-py, pyvisa
    Running setup.py install for pyvisa-py
    Running setup.py install for pyvisa
  Successfully installed pyvisa-py pyvisa
  Cleaning up...
```

`

Note, you should probably also install `pyserial` and `pyusb` to use connected devices.

Comment: I am running jessie, yes. I have everything updated like you suggested at the beginning of your answer, but since I cannot connect to internet I can't use the `pip install pyvisa-py` command. Is there a way I can load it to a usb from a computer with internet access and then put it on my pi?

Comment: without internet, how do you hope to install packages? pip will only reference any cached files/packages/whls

Comment: That's what I'm asking, if there is a way I can do it without a connection.

Comment: in case you missed it    
@K.Schneider this should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/488164

Comment: @K.Schneider "that's what I'm asking, if there is a way I can do it without a connection" - currently, this information is completely missing in your question. Arguably this requirement is more important that the specific package you're trying to install.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev This is old answer, but will add pip install -e